# adding item under specific td in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I am trying to implement the following.

A user enters a sentence into a textbox following which a table is created. An example would be this.

Input: "This is what I want to achieve"

Result:

[image]

Currently, I have the following which builds the header for me with the first letter of each word, however these letters repeat themselves. I need to build the table body now. I can use the same logic to put each word into a table, but what I am struggling to do is add the word under the appropriate section of the table. For example so that the word `'This'` is in the third `<td>` in the first row. I have made many attempts but none have been working so have left the make `tableBody` function as a blank canvas. One idea I had was to add an id of the first letter to each item in the first row, which i could then use later for the complete words, but was unable to put them under the appropriate first letter.

```js
var $ = jQuery.noConflict();

var app = app || {};
(function() {
  "use strict";

  app.initialize = {
      init: function() {
        app.checkWord.splitWords();
      }
    },

    app.checkWord = {

    splitWords: function() {

        $(".calculate").click(function(){
            app.checkWord.firstLetter();
            var result = $("#text-input").val().split(" ");
            app.createTable.tableHeader(result.sort());
        });
        
    },

    firstLetter: function() {
        
    }
},

app.createTable = {

    tableHeader: function(sentence) {  
        $.each(sentence, function(index, item) {
            $(".words-row").append("<td>" + sentence[index].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + "</td>");
        });        
    },

    tableBody: function() {

    }

}

    app.docOnReady = {
      init: function() {
        app.initialize.init();
      }
    };

  $(document).ready(app.docOnReady.init);
  $(window).resize(app.docOnResize.init);

})(jQuery);
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header">
</div>

<div id="main">

  <div>
    <textarea id="text-input" name="textarea" rows="5" cols="25">This is what I want to achieve</textarea>
    <button class="calculate">Calculate</button>
  </div>

  <div id="results-table">
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr class="words-row"></tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to point you in the right direction instead of giving you the desired answer.

Forget about working with DOM Tree. Figure out what words belong to what category and only after that do the rendering of your data representation.

Here is quick and dirty javascript to show you how to split the string into multi-dimensional array by first letters.

You will then take the array and output it to table rows, or whatever you want to do with it.

```js
// Your string
var str = 'this is what i want to achieve';

// Split string by space -> creates array of words.
var arr = str.split(' ');

// Resulting array
var result = new Array();

// Go through all words and assing them to resulting multi-dimensional array
for (var i=0; i< arr.length; i++){

  if (typeof result[arr[i][0]] == 'undefined' )
   result[arr[i][0]] = new Array();
    
  result[arr[i][0]].push(arr[i]);
}


/* Print output */
function dump(obj) {
    var out = '';
    for (var i in obj) {
        out += i + ": " + obj[i] + "\n";
    }

    var pre = document.createElement('pre');
    pre.innerHTML = out;
    document.body.appendChild(pre)
}

dump(result);
```